# WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name gets me the application pool name rather than the user name

Tags: c#, iis

On my development machine this line of code correctly returns me the username.

```
public class Constants
{
    public static readonly string Username = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
}
```

But when I deploy the app to a test webserver, I am getting the name of the application pool.

I am using Windows Authentication.

I cant work out why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Windows Authentication is enabled and Anonymous Authentication is disabled in IIS.

```
 <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
       <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
```

Ensure you Application pool is using pass-through authentication for an "Application User" by clicking "Connect As".

Ensure Identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity for Application Pool under which your site is running.

Alternatively, you can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;` to get the user name.

Comment: I did the exact same thing, and my ASP.NET Impersonation is enabled in IIS. And I get a internal server error now. Any idea?